Can I install a clonezilla image from a DVD instead of from a USB thumb drive or USB external drive?
I can install a clonezilla-created Linux image from a USB thumb drive but I'm interested in being able to use Clonezilla Live to install a clonezilla-create image that I have burned onto a DVD.
I can't find any references saying it is not possible to install a CloneZilla DVD image (of Linux). Does anyone know if this is possible?
I have searched through StackExchange and other community sites, Youtube videos for an answer but what I'm really looking for a definite "no, you cannot install a Clonezilla-create image that is on a DVD". I have tried installing with CloneZilla using the device-image and device-device options.

The Ubuntu live installer is too large for a DVD anymore. You are probably not finding anything as just about any installed system will be too large. Perhaps some lightweight system may fit. Often easier just to backup your data, /home, list of installed apps and perhaps other folders if server. Then do new clean install & restore your data.

By image on DVD do you mean an image file? or a booting filesystem created from an image?  The difference may be important because optical disks have their own filesystems that don't work on other types of disk unless they've been rigged to be two types of filesystem at once.

Are you saying that you have burned such an image on a DVD, and you now want to know whether it’s usable?   Or are you asking whether it is possible to burn a Clonezilla image onto a DVD (and, implicitly, whether such an image will be usable)?

In essence, I used Clonezilla to create an image file from one of my working Dell Optiplex 3000 Ubuntu systems which I put on a USB thumb drive.  From there, I copied the thumb drive copy onto another Windows system and used ImgBurn to burn that onto a DVD (DVD-R) as an ISO.  Then I put the DVD into an external DVD drive (USB) attached that to another Dell Optiplex 3000 and then attempted to install the DVD image onto that system with CloneZilla.


I don't understand why you're complicating things so much. You've used (and wasted) a DVD to be read from a USB drive when you had the data in a USB flash drive already? If the target PC has non-working USB ports and an internal optical drive everyone could see the logic here but that NOT being the case makes it nonsensical to say the least. 2. It depends on exactly what you did to burn that DVD but perhaps that's moot anyway because... 3. You can't possibly fit an installed Ubuntu OS onto a 4.7GB DVD even if it's a very frugal installation.


Sadly, using the DVD for the Ubuntu installation is a requirement from my employer and is something that cannot be changed.  Yes, a USB thumb drive is a much better solution (and it works) but it is just not an option.
